# Exception in MultiBinding when Application.DispatcherUnhandledException is registered

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, multibinding

```
<UserControl.Resources>
<DataTemplate x:Key="EditCardNonBuffer">
...
...
<ComboBox.SelectedValue>
    <MultiBinding Mode="TwoWay" Converter="{StaticResource ingredientRowToTypeIDConverter}">
        <Binding Path="GridIngredient.IngredientIngredientTypeRow" />
        <Binding Path="GridIngredient.IngredientStockRowByIngredientStockGridIngredient" />
    </MultiBinding>
</ComboBox.SelectedValue>
...
...
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate x:Key="EditCardBuffer">
...
...
<ComboBox.SelectedValue>
    <MultiBinding Mode="TwoWay" Converter="{StaticResource ingredientRowToTypeIDConverter}">
        <Binding Path="GridIngredient.IngredientIngredientTypeRow" />
        <Binding Path="GridIngredient.IngredientStockRowByIngredientStockGridIngredient" />
    </MultiBinding>
</ComboBox.SelectedValue>
...
...
</DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Background="White" Margin="2,-4,2,0" Visibility="{Binding GridIngredient.IsEditMode, Converter={StaticResource GlobalBooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding}">
            <ContentControl.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding GridIngredient.IngredientIngredientTypeRow.IngredientTypeRow.IsBuffer}" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource EditCardNonBuffer}" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding GridIngredient.IngredientIngredientTypeRow.IngredientTypeRow.IsBuffer}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource EditCardBuffer}" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ContentControl.Style>
        </ContentControl>
    </Border>
```

Converter:

```
public class IngredientRowToTypeIDConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    private SystemDataSet _dataSet;

    public object Convert( object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture )
    {
      if( values.Length > 0 && values[ 0 ] is SystemDataSet.IngredientIngredientTypeRow )
      {
        var row = (SystemDataSet.IngredientIngredientTypeRow) values[ 0 ];
        _dataSet = _dataSet ?? (SystemDataSet) row.Table.DataSet;
        return row.IngredientTypeID;
      }
      else
        MessageBox.Show( "just for debugging" );

      return values;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack( object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture )
    {
      if( value is int && _dataSet != null )
      {
        var ingredientTypeID = (int) value;
        var ingredient = _dataSet.IngredientIngredientType.Where( r => r.IngredientTypeID == ingredientTypeID ).OrderBy( r => r.IngredientRow.LongName ).First();
        var ingredientStock = ingredient.IngredientTypeRow.IsBuffer ? ingredient.IngredientRow.IngredientStockRowByDefaultBuffer : ingredient.IngredientRow.IngredientStockRowByDefaultNonBuffer;
        return new object[] { ingredient, ingredientStock };
      }
      else
        MessageBox.Show( "just for debugging" );

      return new object[] { value };
    }
}
```

Following exception is caught by Application.DispatcherUnhandledException event when I change selected value of combo box.

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at System.Windows.Data.MultiBindingExpression.UpdateSource(Object convertedValue)
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpressionBase.UpdateValue()
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpressionBase.Dirty()
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpressionBase.SetValue(DependencyObject d, DependencyProperty dp, Object value)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(DependencyProperty dp, Object value, PropertyMetadata metadata, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType, Boolean isInternal)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetCurrentValueInternal(DependencyProperty dp, Object value)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.UpdatePublicSelectionProperties()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.SelectionChanger.End()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.SelectionChanger.SelectJustThisItem(ItemInfo info, Boolean assumeInItemsCollection)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
```

But I don't get it when the global exception handler event is not registered.

EDIT:

Notice that one of the bound values of combo box is also bound to a data trigger of the content control to change its data template. The exception ONLY happens when the change in combo box is supposed to change the template as well. The ContentTemplate changes successfully. But why the exception?

Comment: Please show the code from your `Converter`.

Comment: Just added converter and more xaml.

Comment: I can't see any obvious problems, although you should check for `null` before you use the `values` input parameter.

Comment: Just did. It's never null. :( What's peculiar is that the exception never happens if the Application.DispatcherUnhandledException event is not registered. Could you please upvote the question so more people may notice?

Comment: It's more likely that the `Exception` is being caught (but not handled) somewhere in the Framework. If you look in the Output Window when the `Application.DispatcherUnhandledException` event is not handled, is the error still noted?

Comment: No, nothing suspicious in Output when the event is registered. But one thing I've just noticed that the exception only happens when the new selected item changes the template of the content control.